# How to identify gpg key IDs so they may be deleted

Tags: debian, apt, gpg, apt-key

Upon executing `apt-key list`, I see a key which I wish to remove.

```
...
pub   rsa2048 2017-11-24 [SC]
      3241 413F 3CE0 B919 E82F  DCA0 6239 92CF C9A9 7C2C
uid           [ unknown] John Doe <john.doe@gmail.com>
sub   rsa2048 2017-11-24 [E]
...
```

`man apt-key` tells me that I may delete a key by executing `apt-key del keyid`.  It also tells me that `list` (aka `finger`) will list trusted keys with fingerprints, so I am assuming that `3241 413F 3CE0 B919 E82F  DCA0 6239 92CF C9A9 7C2C` is the fingerprint and not the keyid.  I've messed around with `gpg --list-keys` and `gpg --list-public-keys`, however, it doesn't list any keys but creates `~/.gnupg/` with various non-text files which do not display the key IDs.

How can I identify the keyid so I may delete the key?

PS.  Before asking this question, I searched for a solution, and some recommend not using "short key ids".  If I should not be deleting keys by the keyid as described by `man apt-key`, please provide the appropriate way.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The keyid is the **last 8 characters of the gpg key's fingerprint**, which is that long hex-code under `pub`

In your case it is: `sudo apt-key del C9A97C2C`

**Reference**:

- [How can I remove gpg key that I added using apt-key add -?](https://askubuntu.com/a/846877/565006)

Comment: Thanks Mark,  I had actually seen that post, but considering that `man apt-key` does not also mirror this information, it made me question whether I am actually doing this correct by using the frowned upon short key ID.

Comment: Wow, that's seriously.... not obvious from the tools.  Great answer, thanks.

Comment: It seems it is also valid to use the whole ID string

Comment: yeah, apt-key and gpg have some serious brainfarts when it comes to CLI UX